# confidence limits on $m$th value from $n$ sorted independent samples from discrete uniform distribution (with $n$ choices)

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, confidence-interval, python

You have $n$ samples, each chosen independently from integers $0, 1, \ldots, n-1$ with equal probability (so although there are $n$ samples and $n$ values to choose from, it is not a permutation).

You then sort those samples into increasing order.  Call these sorted samples $x_0, x_1, \ldots , x_{n-1}$. In other words, $x_0 \le x_1 \le \cdots \text{etc.}\cdots \le x_{n-1} $

I am interested in the probability distribution of $x_m$, and in particular the confidence limits on that distribution.  That is, for a given confidence level $c$ (equal to, say, $0.05$ or $0.95$), the value of $a$ (an integer) such that $p(x_m \ge a) \approx c$.

It seems to me *similar* to a binomial distribution, in that $p(x_m \ge a)$ would be the probability that no more than $m$ sample values (out of the total $n$) should be $< a$, which for any individual sample has probability $a/n$, hence this looks like the cumulative density function of the binomial distribution $F(m; n, a/n)$ (based on the $F(k; n, p)$ notation used [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Binomial_distribution&oldid=962805501#Cumulative_distribution_function)).  But then I start to get confused, because the confidence levels of that distribution (e.g. the "percent point function" that I could compute in SciPy using [scipy.stats.binom.ppf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom.html)) would be the values of $k$ such that $F(k; n, p) = c$ for a given $n$ and $p$, but here it is a different functional dependence, because $m$ and $n$ are given and we want $a$, which also makes me suspicious over whether this cumulative density function is based on the correct conditional probabilities.

Any assistance appreciated, both regarding the correct analytical expression and also any info about library functions to compute this in Python.  Many thanks.

Comment: I would have written that you have a sample consisting of $n$ observations, rather than that you have $n$ samples. But sometimes even respectable people write it the way you did.

Comment: Yes your first approach is correct. Then just find $a$ that yields a probability value close to $c$, adding “without going over” or “without going under” as you like.

Comment: Thank you @Michael - so if I've correctly understood you, the $F(m;n,a/n) \approx c$ is correct, so for example I can use `scipy.stats.binom.cmf` in SciPy to evaluate $F$, I just shouldn't use the corresponding `ppf` function because this solves for $m$; I should instead should solve for $a$. Is that correct please? And if so, do you have any suggestion about the best way to do this computationally please?

Comment: I don't know what the ppf function is. You can just vary $a \in \{1, ..., n\}$ to find the best one (as you describe the problem above, it seems $n,m$ are fixed). So it evaluates the $F$ function at most $n$ times.  Or, if $n$ is very large, you could use the fact that $F(m,n,a/n)$ is nonincreasing with $a$ to use a bisection search, which would evaluate $F$ at most $O(\log(n))$ times.

Comment: @Michael Thank you.  (The `ppf`, percent point function, is mentioned on the page that I linked in the question, but I won't try to use it, just solve for $a$.)  Just the reassurance that the $F$ function is appropriate to this problem is the main thing I think -- I was starting to doubt myself it because I know how easy it can be to use some argument for a certain probability distribution that seems superficially correct but relies on subtly wrong assumptions.

Comment: By the way, yes, $n$ and $m$ are fixed. $n$ is a constant. $m$ is fixed for this problem, although I will want to compute the result separately for each possible value of $m$. The library code to evaluate $F$ will in fact accept an array of $m$ values, but that may not be of much benefit here so would probably just put the whole solution in a loop over $m$. I'm not too worried about optimising CPU at this stage, but this is all motivated by wanting to avoid a Monte Carlo approach that required too much memory. (Trying to assist a user of a compute platform that I help to support.)